# Why TestInitialize cannot be used with a static method?

Tags: c#, testing, mstest

I'm learning about **MSTest** and **C#** and, when developing a test using `TestInitialize`, I couldn't understand why this attribute cannot be used with a `static` method. Could someone explain to me?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello @KarenPayne! I was researching **TestInitialize** because I needed to make a request for each test and when I tried to use `static` in the method, the tests did not run. So I wanted to know why TestInitialize cannot be used with a static method.

Comment: You will need to research into the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx) to learn why.

Comment: Hi @KarenPayne, I found [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/477ad52b422c529da653ec7afe7edab50ce410c2/src/TestFramework/MSTest.Core/Attributes/Lifecycle/Initialization/TestInitializeAttribute.cs) but I still don't understand why can't I use `private`. If not, could you point me to the correct location? But if so, could you help me with this question?

Comment: Best guess is private is less accessible scope-wise than the class.